# React Profiler - Start profiling and reload page?

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

Using the React dev Tools and the Profiler, is there a way to start the profiler and reload the page? Similar to how the Chrome dev tools has the button to start profiling and reload the page.

Currently if I start the profiler and refresh the page it stops the profiler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The React Dev Tools have since added the reload and start profiling button.

[image]

Comment: I have Firefox 89.0 (64bit) and React Developer tools plugin Version 4.13.5 and I don't have a reload button. Did they took it away?

Comment: Here is the issue that says Firefox doesn't support the necessary APIs to add the reload and start profiling button. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/21384

Answer (score 3):

> To profile the initial render, you can use the **reload and start profiling** button, which will reload the page and start profiling before the initial render. You can then continue or stop recording as you normally would.

[source](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/profiling-performance-with-react-developer-tools)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can hit record and reload the page, but if you want to measure the page load, I think you can put the profiler in your code and then console log the results. Something like this:

```
logProfile = (id, phase, actualTime, baseTime, startTime, commitTime, interactions) => {
  console.log(`--------- ${id}'s ${phase.toUpperCase()} phase: ---------`);
  console.log(`Time spent rendering ${actualTime} ms`); // Time spent rendering the Profiler and its descendants for the most recent "mount" or "update" render.
  console.log(`Base time: ${baseTime} ms`); // Duration of the most recent render time for each individual component within the Profiler tree.
  console.log(`React render start time (since component mounted): ${startTime} ms`); // When the Profiler began the recently committed render.
  console.log(`React render commit time (since component mounted): ${commitTime} ms`); // The time at which the current commit took place.
  console.log(interactions);
};
```

And then in your render:

```
<Profiler id="entities" onRender={this.logProfile}><Page /></Profiler>
```